# what is slab entries in proc/meminfo?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

Slab — The total amount of memory, in kilobytes, used by the kernel to cache data structures for its own use.

My question is that if any process create its own slab then this slab memory go to slab or process's PSS part?

memory allocated by kmalloc goes to PSS or slab?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure whether I understand your question.
If you want to use slab allocator, you can use the following APIs:

> kmem_cache_t* kmem_cache_create(const char *name, size_t size, size_t
>   align, unsigned long flags, void (*ctor)(void*,kmem_cache_t*, unsigned
>   long), (*ctor)(void*,kmem_cache_t*, unsigned long))
>
> void *kmem_cache_alloc(kmem_cache_t *cachep, int flags)

The first API will create a slab allocator for you.
And the second is used to allocate memory.

kmalloc() doesn't use slab.

Comment: thanks, I have read some articles and found that "slab" field is related to kernel in "proc/meminfo". So I want to know that if any kernel module which use kmalloc for 20MB then this memory is count in slab (because kmalloc use kmem_catche slab) or process individual  filed that is RSS

Comment: slab is used to quickly allocate memory for frequently-used data structure.